# Remove "Insert from URL" link in Media upload - WP 3.5

Tags: php, functions, filters, media, media-library

How do I remove the `Insert from URL` link in the new Wordpress 3.5 Add Media popup page? In earlier versions of Wordpress, this worked fine:

```
// removes URL tab in image upload for post
function remove_media_library_tab($tabs) { 
    if (isset($_REQUEST['post_id'])) {
        $post_type = get_post_type($_REQUEST['post_id']);
        if ('premium' == $post_type)
            unset($tabs['library']);
            unset($tabs['type_url']);
    }
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'remove_media_library_tab');
```

Who knows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
add_filter( 'media_view_strings', 'cor_media_view_strings' );
/**
 * Removes the media 'From URL' string.
 *
 * @see wp-includes|media.php
 */
function cor_media_view_strings( $strings ) {
    unset( $strings['insertFromUrlTitle'] );
    return $strings;
}
```

Comment: Works great - well done!

Comment: Is this possible to be done via javascript, I used the media manager in post metabox, so I can't do this via filter since it will ruin the post 'add media' behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The code of default tabs array in new WP is in media.php and looks like this:

```
/**
 * Defines the default media upload tabs
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @return array default tabs
 */
function media_upload_tabs() {
    $_default_tabs = array(
        'type' => __('From Computer'), // handler action suffix => tab text
        'type_url' => __('From URL'),
        'gallery' => __('Gallery'),
        'library' => __('Media Library')
    );

    return apply_filters('media_upload_tabs', $_default_tabs);
}
```

If you want only remove upload from url by default you shoud change your function to:

```
// removes URL tab in image upload for post
function remove_media_library_tab($tabs) { 
    unset($tabs['type_url']);
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'remove_media_library_tab');
```

Not tested but it should work fine.

Edit: Not work because this array is used in other place. 
If you want just remove the link you can use this work around:

```
function remove_media_library_tab(){
    ?>
    <style>
        .media-menu a:last-child{ display:none}
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_media_library_tab');
```

Comment: This does not work I'm afraid. Maybe you could try it yourself and debug the code...?

Comment: I edit my answer, you can check new code (works in my WP) or just copy css rule to your style.css. I can't find method to remove this option from php.

Comment: Cor van Noorloos answer works better as it unsets it rather than hiding it through CSS. However, this was a good approach which is why I have upvoted it.

Comment: Yep, it's better ;) I just check it - it use a new filter from WP 3.5 which I did not know ;)